# How to display the data fetched from the database in the form

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

$    // First i am sending the php code which executes the sql query this code executes the query to get the data from the data base and stores all that in the get_row1 and sends it as a response to the ajax $

```
<?php 
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $data = mysql_select_db("testme", $connect);
    $identity = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM student_demo WHERE id=1";
    $getdata = mysql_query($query);

    $get_row1 = mysql_fetch_array($getdata);

    $data1 = array(
            $get_row1[0],
        $get_row1[1],
        $get_row1[2],
        $get_row1[3]
    );
    print_r($data1); 
?>
```

$   //This sends the $data1 back to the ajax code $

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        temp1 = xmlhttp.responseText.split("=>");
        alert(temp1);
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('.data' + i).val(tmp1[i]);
            if (tmp[i] == "[0]") {
                document.getelementById("c_name").value = temp1[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "process.php?id=" + ID, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Now what changes i should make to get the values from the array temp1 to display in the text box$

Comment: I can see that you are using `$` in for loop assuming its aliased to `jQuery` why not use `$.ajax()` ?

Comment: What is tmp array? You mention temp, but you also have tmp.

Comment: You are asking how to correctly parse response from ajax ? In other words, how to convert it to JS-array?

Comment: In general the js code performs a request to the php page and fetches the printed data by the id. Do you want this data in a js array?

Comment: @2-Stroker really I would prefer jQuery instead of the 'normal' ajax!

Comment: yes Vadym Kovalenko how to do that. So that i can print the result in the text box

Answer (score 1):

In your php code, you should better encode response to JSON:

```
data1=array($get_row1[0],
        $get_row1[1],
        $get_row1[2],
        $get_row1[3]);

json_encode($data1);
```

And then, in JS code, you can parse response string using `JSON.parse`:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    temp1=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    console.log(temp1); // this way you can see exact structure of an object in browser console
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        $('.data'+i).val(tmp1[i]); // not sure what is that. If you are already using jQuery, then you can do everything even simpler
        if(tmp[i]=="[0]")
        {
            document.getElementById("c_name").value=temp1[i]; // see here getElementById - javascript is case sensitive
        }
    }

}
```

Note: `JSON.parse` is available in modern browsers only. In IE7, for instance, you will get an error because of that. To fix this problem you can download [this](https://raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js) small piece of JavaScript.

For jQuery solution take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)